# Find Rectangular Unitary Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, control-theory, linear-control

While describing a feedback control system, I came to a result in which it was necessary that $\mathbf{C} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ was such that $\mathbf{C}\mathbf{C}^{T}=\mathbf{I}$...

In my case, I have a system with 12 state variables: $[x\,\,y\,\,z\,\,u\,\,v\,\,w\,\,\phi\,\,\theta\,\,\psi\,\,p\,\,q\,\,r]^{T}$ and 4 outputs $[x\,\,y\,\,z\,\,\psi]^{T}$ which are just a selection of some of the state variables, which means my $\mathbf{C}$ is this:

$$
\mathbf{C}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and obsviously:

$$
\mathbf{C^{T}}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

With Matlab, I confirmed that, for this matrix, $\mathbf{C}\mathbf{C}^{T}=\mathbf{I}$ holds.

So I would like to find a way, preferably in a math proof style, to describe the necessary properties of this matrix $\mathbf{C}$ in terms of rows and columns elements.

Or, even better than that, find counter-examples that show in which cases this would not hold.

For me, it seems that this would go wrong if we didn't have only $1$'s and if we had more than one non-zero element in a single row (an output would be a linear combination of two or more states).

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of examples that don't have $0$'s and $1$'s.  For example,
consider the block matrix form

$$ C = \pmatrix{ A & | & B}$$
where $A$ is $m \times (n-m)$ and $B$ is $m \times m$.  Then $C C^T = A A^T + B B^T$.  As long as the entries of $A$ are small enough that the greatest eigenvalue of $A A^T$ is less than $1$, $I - A A^T$ will be positive definite, and then there will be  $B$ such that $B B^T = I - A A^T$.  For example, we could take the positive definite square root or the Cholesky decomposition.

Comment: Thank you! Is it also correct to say that $\mathbf{C}$ is unitary iff its rows are orthonormal vectors?